# ng-style not working for IE11 and Chrome63 for progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am new using AngularJS.

I am able to calculate the dynamic value using `{{}}` but new CSS is not replaced with the old one.

```
 <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="width:{{survey.progressbar.width}}">
```

When I am using

```
style="width:{{survey.progressbar.width}}"
```

I am getting expected results in Chrome but not in IE11

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible in order to reproduce the exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the correct way to use the `ng-style`. use it like this.

```
 <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{'width' : survey.progressbar.width}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have counter same problem before.
That's because you are not understand the Angularjs ng-style technique. See below doc:

The Angularjs provide two directives `ngClass` & `ngStyle` both of them are able to receive an expression, the expression result is one of the list below:

1. A string, using references to css class name each of them are separate by space.
2. An array of css class names.
3. An object, it's a set of key-value pair, key is the css class name and the value is the boolean. The class will be used when value eq `true`.

Back to your code.

You prefer to use `{{expression}}` to get a dynamic value .

- The first row you use the `ng-style`,it  check expression as a string"width:value" and there is no css class name match so it's inoperative
- The second row you just use style attribute, it may browser layout engine difference.